# assignment makes pointer from integer without cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers

I have googled this and see many answers, but none fits my situation. This is my main():

```
char * cString;
puts("Please enter data you want to encrypt.");
cString = getInput(cString, &iStringSize);
printf("The message is: %s\n\n", cString);

char * strEncrypt;
strEncrypt = encrypt(cString, offset);
printf("The encrypted message is: %s\n\n", strEncrypt);

return 0;
```

This program basically reads in an arbitrary input, then encrypt it. This is the getInput function:

```
char * getInput(char *cString, int * iStringSize)
{
    puts("Begin reading input.");
    char buffer[CHUNK];
    int iBufferSize;
    while(fgets(buffer, CHUNK - 1, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        iBufferSize = strlen(buffer);
        *iStringSize += iBufferSize;
        cString = realloc(cString, sizeof(char) * (*iStringSize + 1));
        strcat(cString, buffer);
    }
    printf("String size is: %d\n", *iStringSize);
    puts("Reading successful");
    return cString;
}
```

**As shown above, cString is char pointer. The getInput function also returns char pointer. However, I keep getting the message: assignment makes pointer from integer without cast [enabled by default]**

This happens when I compile the code.

The same happens to this function

```
char * encrypt(char *str, int offset)
{
    puts("Begin encryption.");
    char * strEncrypt = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        //substitution algorithm using int offset variable.
        //I accessed str and strEncrypt using pointer arithmetic
    }

    puts("Encryption success!");
    return strEncrypt;
}
```

Please no suggestion on error handling of realloc.

Comment: Is your getInput function declared before it is used?  If not, the compiler will think it returns an int.

Comment: at what line you are getting warning?

Comment: Please mention the line number where you are getting error. And note that in `getInput()` function you are incrementing `iStringSize` value, before that it should be initialised to zero.

Comment: I get the warnings in these lines: cString = getInput(cString, &iStringSize);  
strEncrypt = encrypt(cString, offset);    so when I assign the result of functions to the pointer.

Comment: Googling the exact error message in the title, nearly *half* of the many answers fit your exact situation, so I'm lost why you think otherwise.  And this isn't the only problem in your code. You're passing an indeterminate pointer `cString` to `getInput` invoking undefined behavior. Sending it to `realloc` just solidifies that improper action. Initialize it to NULL or a *valid* allocation result prior to calling `getInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare getInpyt and encrypt function before their first use otherwise compiler assumes these functions return int and accept variable number of parameters.

You can declare them by using any one of 3 ways given below.

1. Include appropriate header files containing their declarations.
2. Include declarations manually in global scope or local scope before you first access them.
3. Move the definition of these functions before you first access them.